# centering flex items vertically and side by side at same level

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been trying to centering the the flex items vertically but with that I also want them side by side at same level

tried:

1)to parent block

```
display:flex;

align-items:center;
```

but it doesn't make it at same level **(my content to second flex item will not be the same in length)**, required some generic solution

2)padding top and bottom 
as **(my content to second flex item will not be the same in length)** requirement not satisfy, it doesn't work either

Its currently use with grid, but as IE11 doesnt support grid, I'm converting into flex

please review the codepen after applying align-items to [flex](https://codepen.io/nileshpatil380/pen/ZEQYOQO)

codepen with [grid](https://codepen.io/nileshpatil380/pen/VweYjjd)

ref-image [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYEp.png)

Comment: don't add links in code blocks please. the editor told you to not add links but provide a snipped so we don't have to look at an external website to review and tweak the code.

Comment: @Paulie_D please ref-image 
update with changes

Comment: IE11 does support grid (Internet Explorer was the first to implement it, I believe) but with a lot of caveats with prefixes and some unsupported values, as it uses an [older specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/). Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't do that with flexbox since you have aligned the items to the center which overrides the height equalisation of `align-items:stretch`

Your only option is to wrap those elements in a separate div and center **that**.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.one {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.two {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="item one">One</div>
    <div class="item two">some text will be here and it will not defined against its length</div>
  </div>
</div>
```